# How do we get the preview frame using CameraX?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

I am working on a project which uses CameraX to show the camera preview on a `TextureView`. The code hails from this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#5). I have used the `setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener()` method to update the `TextureView`.

```
private fun startCamera() {
    val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
        setTargetAspectRatio( Rational( 1 , 1 ) )
        setTargetResolution( Size( 640 , 640 ) )
    }.build()
    val preview = Preview( previewConfig )
    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener {
        val parent = cameraTextureView?.parent as ViewGroup
        parent.removeView( cameraTextureView )
        cameraTextureView?.surfaceTexture = it.surfaceTexture
        parent.addView( cameraTextureView , 0)
        updateTransform()
    }
    preview.removePreviewOutputListener()
    CameraX.bindToLifecycle( this , preview )
}
```

My question is how do I get the raw `byte[]` object from preview frames using CameraX. I expect something which is similar to `onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)` method.

> Basically, I want the realtime frames ( in `byte[]` or `Bitmap` ) from the preview using CameraX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will use [ImageAnalysis](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze). The preview frames will be passed to your Analyzer in YUV_420_888 format.

If necessary, you can request non-blocking analysis mode. I would recommend to set a Handler for your Analyzer, so that the camera callbacks not arrive on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Cohn's for the answer.

Comment: What if you also use `VideoCapture` together with the `Preview`? In that case, you get an exception by trying to "bind too many use cases". See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61524671/1680301

Comment: In camerax，can use only one image use case and  only one video use case。so ImageAnaysis and VideoCapture together is fine。 Use the ImageAnaysis's callback to get preview frame image，then render the image by GPUImageView to Preview

Comment: @Alex Cohn I hope You have any examples to implement it.

Comment: @newbie I have not touched this field for a while, so I cannot show working examples at this time.

Comment: Don't worry. take your time.

Comment: "render the image by GPUImageView to Preview" How? @ProBlc