# Is it possible to combine Preview, ImageAnalysis, and VideoCapture with CameraX?

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-camerax

Is it possible to bind `Preview`, `ImageAnalysis`, and `VideoCapture` at the same time? Combined in pairs, all possible combinations (ie. `Preview`+`ImageAnalysis`, `Preview`+`VideoCapture`, and `ImageAnalysis`+`VideoCapture`) work perfectly fine but binding all three together throws the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No supported surface combination is found for camera device - Id : 1.  May be attempting to bind too many use cases.
    at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.getSuggestedResolutions(Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.java:193)
    at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.calculateSuggestedResolutions(CameraX.java:943)
    at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.bindToLifecycle(CameraX.java:293)
    at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ProcessCameraProvider.java:229)
```

Is there any workaround that allows me to use `ImageAnalysis` and at the same time record a video?

Comment: This limitation could be device dependent, I am not sure. But if you have ImageAnalysis, you can run your custom video recorder (based on MediaCodec).

Comment: Any success on this one?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up implementing my own solution using Camera2. I don't know if anything has changed with CameraX since my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are limits to the number of simultaneous outputs that are due to the camera hardware pipeline's scaler unit limitations.

In general, 3 parallel YUV outputs aren't supported outside of high-end devices.

You can look at the many tables here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice#createCaptureSession(android.hardware.camera2.params.SessionConfiguration)

and see what kinds of parallel outputs can be set up, on the various hardware levels (PRIV and YUV are what these usecases operate on).

A FULL device can do it, as long as the analysis runs at 640x480 or lower.  But LEGACY and LIMITED cannot.

That said, you can use ImageAnalysis frames to drive a preview, but it's certainly a bit less convenient - may require using the NDK or other annoyances.

Comment: Using `ImageAnalysis` for the preview is not possible in some cases. For example, when doing image recognition you need the frames to be quite small to minimise delays. I ended up using `Camera2` and passing 3 surfaces to `CameraDevice.createCaptureSession()` for preview, image analysis, and video capture, respectively. That worked smoothly and the million dollar question now is: if I can do it with `Camera2`, why can't I do it with `CameraX`?

Comment: It may work on your test device, but there are likely many devices it won't work on.  CameraX should work similarly on your device, however, so it's odd that there's a problem. Possibly a higher resolution was selected by CameraX than what you manually set up?