# How to schedule per frame callback with any form of android video capture

Tags: android, android-camerax

I try to make an android app which will record yaw of phone into a binary file per frame of video capture. I initially tried to make that work with OpenCV, but the fact that video writer doesn't work seem to introduce a lot of complications. Sequentially I looked into camera2 API and CameraX in hopes of using them instead. However I found no way to implement per frame callbacks. I thought of making a service app which will intercept camera events in non blocking manner and then transfer seconds to frames since my framerate is fixed 30 at the moment but I'm struggling to find a way here as well. Can anyone suggest a way to achieve the expected result?

I also tried to see the composition of android mp4 (because from my understanding it could carry per frame metadata) but to no avail.

**Update:**
I.ve managed to record video with cameraX while calling the writing of the yaw on background thread from sensor callback set to duration of one frame from framerate. But this is still not very precise. I've tried to add ImageAnalysis UseCase to my UseCaseGroup since its called per frame, but I have an issue which was already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61524671/is-it-possible-to-combine-preview-imageanalysis-and-videocapture-with-camerax). Anyone knows how to resolve this, or any workaround to achieve per frame callback?

Answer (score 2):

Camera2 provides per-frame callbacks in various ways - the simplest probably being the [onCaptureComplete](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback#onCaptureCompleted(android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession,%20android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest,%20android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult)) callback.

That callback will get all the frame metadata, which includes the start of exposure timestamp.  You can use that timestamp to match up to sensor yaw information and its timestamps, and then send that on to whatever recording mechanism you have.

CameraX also lets you hook into this via:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/camera2/interop/Camera2Interop.Extender?hl=en#setSessionCaptureCallback(android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback)

if there's no existing convenient path.